# wrong output in my program using hashTable

Tags: c

I've created a hash table and I'm inserting things into it but for some reason,
after I put things on the table when I go to print from the table she makes a wrong print.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <math.h>


    typedef  struct hash Hash;



    typedef struct utilizador{
        char nick[6];
        char nome[26];
    }
struct hash{
        int quantidade, table_size;
        utilizador **itens;}

    Hash* criateHash(int table_size){
        Hash* ha= (Hash*)malloc(sizeof(Hash));
        if(ha!=NULL) {
            int i;
            ha->table_size = table_size;
            ha->itens = (utilizador **) malloc(table_size * sizeof(utilizador *));
        }
        if(ha->itens==NULL) {
            free(ha);
            return NULL;
        }
        ha->quantidade=0;
        for(int i=0; i< ha->table_size; i++){
            ha->itens[i]=NULL;
            }
        return ha;
    }

    int string_value(char *string){
        int i, valor=0; 
        int tam= strlen(string);
        for(i=0; i< tam; i++){
            valor=  pow(31,tam-1 )* (int) string[i]+valor;
            }
        return valor;
    }


    int hash_function(int chave, int table_size, Hash *ha){

        int position=(chave%table_size);

        if (ha->itens[position]==NULL)
            return position;
        else {
            for (int j = 0; j < table_size; j++) {
                position = position + j;
                if(position>table_size)
                    return -1;
                else if (ha->itens[position] == NULL) {
                    return position;
                }

            }
            return -1;
        }

    }

    int insereHash(Hash* ha, utilizador *a, int table_size){
        int i, check, chave;
        check=searchHash(ha, a, table_size);
        if(check==-1) {
            chave=string_value(a[0].nick);
            i = hash_function(chave, table_size, ha);
            if (i != -1) {
                ha->itens[i] = a;
                ha->itens[i]->activo=true;
                printf("%d %d ",check, i);
                printf("+ utilizador %s criado\n",ha->itens[i]->nick );

            } else if (i==-1)
                printf("hash não tem espaço");
        }else if (check!=-1){
            printf("%d", check);
            printf("+ nick %s usado previamente\n", a[0].nick);
        }

    }


    int searchHash(Hash* ha, utilizador *a, int table_size){
        int chave=string_value(a[0].nick);

        int position=(chave%table_size);
        if(ha->itens[position]->nick!=NULL) {
            if (str_compare(ha->itens[position]->nick, a[0].nick) == 0)
                return position;

            else {
                for (int j = 0; j < table_size; j++) {
                    position = position + j;
                    if (position > table_size)
                        return -1;
                    else if(ha->itens[position]->nick==NULL)
                        j++;
                    else if (str_compare(ha->itens[position]->nick, a[0].nick) == 0) {
                        return position;
                    }

                }

            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    void input(utilizador *a, char *comando, char *aux) {
        fgets(aux, 35, stdin);
        sscanf(aux, "%s %s  %99[^\n] ", comando, &a[0].nick, &a[0].nome);

    }

    int str_compare( char *string1, char *string2){
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            if (string1[i] != string2[i]) {
                return 1;
            }
        }return 0;
    }

    int table_size=23;
    utilizador ar_temp[1];
    char comando[2];
    char aux[35];
    int pos;

    Hash *ha;
    int main() {

        ha = criateHash(table_size);
        while((strcmp (comando, "X"))!=0 && (strcmp (comando, "x")!=0)) {

            input(ar_temp, comando, aux);

            if ((strcmp (comando, "U")==0)) {
                insereHash(ha, ar_temp, table_size);
            }
    }
    for(int g=0; g<table_size; g++){
            printf("%s ",ha->itens[g]->nick);
        }



        return 0;
    }
```

the input tha i use is:
U asdre ana
U qwert joa
U qwert pedro
U hjklm gomes 
U ertyu ana
U hhudr humberto
U e5sxs wis
U 2kkji toba
U p07hm rojao
U zxcvb tutu
x

and my output is:

```
    -1 19 + utilizador asdre criado
    -1 22 + utilizador qwert criado
    22+ nick qwert usado previamente
    -1 10 + utilizador hjklm criado
    -1 11 + utilizador ertyu criado
    -1 20 + utilizador hhudr criado
    19+ nick e5sxs usado previamente
    -1 7 + utilizador 2kkji criado
    -1 5 + utilizador p07hm criado
    10+ nick zxcvb usado previamente
    10+ nick zxcvb usado previamente
    (null) (null) (null) (null) (null) zxcvb (null) zxcvb (null) (null) zxcvb zxcvb (null) (null) (null) (null) (null) 

(null) (null) zxcvb zxcvb (null) zxcvb 
Process finished with exit code 0
```

My problem is: why the other values I inserted earlier in the table are not there and how can I resolve this?
Can you help me?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately your posted code does not compile. `struct hash{` is missing a closing brace and it uses `utilizador` before its defined and more. Could you post code that compiles please? It also contains numerous compiler warnings. Turning on cmopiler warnings and fixing them will help solve your problem, or make it easier to answer. `-Wall -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -Wextra -Wconversion -std=c99 -pedantic` is a good set of warnings to use.

Answer (score 0):

Your hash table stores pointers to instances of "struct utilizador".  However, every time you call `insereHash`, you are passing the same `ar_temp` instance, which you are overwriting on every call to `input`.

That's why you print the same string multiple times at the end - the entries are in the right place, but you overwrote the data.

You want:

```
 ha->itens:  [.| |.|.| ]
              |   | |
              |   | +-> {"asdre","ana"}
              |   +---> {"qwert","joa"}  
              +-------> {"zxcvb","tutu"}
```

You have:

```
 ha->itens:  [.| |.|.| ]
              |   | |
              +---+-+-> {"zxcvb","tutu"} <-- ar_temp
```

Comment: 237/5000
I finally understood what is happening.
  I am doing ha-> items [i] point to the address of ar_temp ... my question is how do I copy the value from one to another already tried strcpy (ha-> items [i] -> nick, ar_temp [0 ] -> nick) and did not work.