# Why is my print function overwriting previous entries with the last entry in the following code?

Tags: c, hashtable

This is the beginning of a simple program that will store user entries in a hash table. It's still very basic (haven't added a linked list yet to deal with collisions, the hash function is very simple and is a temporary placeholder for a more robust one, I haven't dealt with freeing up all malloc'd memory yet, etc), but I want to get the bare-bones functionality figured out first before I go any further.

In this version my latest entry seems to overwrite the previous ones. It looks like the entries are still in the right spots (as decided by the hash function), but somehow the last one is the one that gets placed everywhere.

Sorry, I know it's a lot of code, but I'm not sure how to create a smaller version of this code to isolate the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUF_SIZE_WORDS 4096
#define BUF_SIZE_NUMBERS 256
#define MAX_WORDS 10

typedef struct tablestruct
{
    int val;
    char* text;
    struct tablestruct *next;
}
table;


// declare the hashing function that takes in the string to be hashed and the length of it
unsigned int hash(char *str, int length);

// // declare a linked list creation function
// lnode *createnode(char *str, htnode *hashtable);

// declare a hash table printing function
void print_ht(table *array[MAX_WORDS]);


int number_input();
int word_input(int num_words, table *array[MAX_WORDS]);
void empty_stdin();

int main(void)
{
    // call number_input() to ask user for number of words they'd like to store, save that in word_count
    int word_count = number_input();

    // create hash table
    table *array[MAX_WORDS];

    for (int j = 0; j < MAX_WORDS; j++)
    {
        array[j] = malloc(sizeof(table));
        array[j]->val = j;
    }

    // add some kind of a memory check?

    // PUT word_input inside the if statement to make sure it worked?
    // call word_input() and store the result in success
    int success = word_input(word_count, array);
    // if not successful:
    if (!success)
    {
        fputs ("some kind of problem with word_input\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    // printf("\ncurrent address of the hash table: %p\n", &array[0]);

    printf("printing hash table: \n");

    print_ht(array);

    // REMEMBER TO FREE WHATEVER'S MALLOC'ED
}

int number_input(void)
{
    // a bunch of code is borrowed from David's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52920852/why-is-the-following-code-not-allowing-me-to-get-user-input-with-fgets-yet-works?noredirect=1#comment92940817_52920852

    int num_words = 0,       /* number of words to enter */
        word_count_check = 0;          /* word count */

    char buffer[BUF_SIZE_NUMBERS] = "";    /* buffer of sufficient size for input */

    for (;;) /* loop continually until valid input of NUMBER OF WORDS USER WANTS TO ENTER or user cancels */
    {
        printf ("how many words would you like to enter? [1-%d]: ", MAX_WORDS);
        // check for cancellation of input
        if (!fgets (buffer, BUF_SIZE_NUMBERS, stdin))
        {
            fputs ("user canceled input\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }

        // check if user simply hit enter w/o typing anything
        if(buffer[0] == '\n')
        {
            printf("please enter a value\n");
            continue;
        }

        size_t inlength = strlen(buffer);

        if (inlength && buffer[inlength - 1] == '\n')
        {
            // printf("hurray!\n");
            buffer[--inlength] = 0;
        }
        else if (inlength == BUF_SIZE_NUMBERS - 1) /* the line was too long */
        {
            printf("you've entered too many characters... please stick to a maximum of %i\n", BUF_SIZE_NUMBERS);
            empty_stdin();
            // continue;
        }

        // make sure user actually entered a proper int
        if (sscanf (buffer, "%d", &num_words) != 1) /* sscanf is used for conversion */
        {
            fputs ("invalid conversion to int; please provide valid input\n", stderr);
            continue;
        }

        // check if the number entered is out of range
        if (num_words < 1 || num_words > MAX_WORDS)
            fprintf (stderr, "%2d out of valid range.\n", num_words);
        else
            break; /*if the input has been validated, we can now break out of the for loop */
    }

    return(num_words);
}

int word_input(int num_words, table *array[MAX_WORDS])
{
    int word_count = 0;

    for(;;) /* loop until word_count == num_words is achieved */
    {
        // declare an array for storing input string
        char buffer[BUF_SIZE_WORDS];
        char valid_input[BUF_SIZE_WORDS];

        // prompt user for input
        printf("\nplease enter a string: ");

        // get input and check for CTRL+D
        if (!fgets(buffer, BUF_SIZE_WORDS, stdin))
        {
            fputs ("user canceled input\n", stderr);
            exit(1);
        }

         // check if user simply hit enter w/o typing anything
        if(buffer[0] == '\n')
        {
            printf("please enter a word that's more than 0 characters\n");
            // empty_stdin();
            continue;
        }

        size_t inlength = strlen(buffer);

        if (inlength && buffer[inlength - 1] == '\n')
        {
            buffer[--inlength] = 0;

            // get rid of trailing spaces using sscanf
            sscanf(buffer, "%s", valid_input);
            inlength = strlen(valid_input);

            printf("string length: %zu\n", inlength);

            // call the hash function to get the hash code
            int result = hash(&valid_input[0], inlength);

            table *newnode = malloc(sizeof(table));

            // store the current string in the newnode->text
            newnode->text = valid_input;
            // strcpy(newnode->text, valid_input); ??
            // newnode->val = inlength;

            // confirm string has been stored
            printf("you've entered: %s\n", newnode->text);

            // attach the node to correct slot in the hash table -- ADD LINKED LIST FUNCTIONALITY HERE TO DEAL WITH COLLISIONS!
            array[result]->next = newnode;
            // printf("address of the current HT entry is: %p\n", newnode);

            // increment word count
            word_count++;
            printf("word_count = %i\n", word_count);

            if (word_count == num_words)
            {
                 printf("\nDONE!\n\n");
                 return word_count;
            }
        }
        // check if the user entered too many characters
        else if (inlength == BUF_SIZE_WORDS - 1) /* the line was too long */
        {
            printf("you've entered too many characters... please stick to a maximum of %i\n", BUF_SIZE_WORDS);
            empty_stdin();
        }
    }
    // return word_count;
}


/* helper function to remove any chars left in input buffer */
void empty_stdin()
{
    int c = getchar();
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}

// THIS HASH FUNCTION IS TOO BASIC AND NEEDS TO BE REPLACED WITH SOMETHING BETTER
unsigned int hash(char *str, int length)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
    {
        sum += str[j];
    }
    printf("here's what the hashing function is returning: %i\n", (sum % MAX_WORDS));
    return sum % MAX_WORDS;
}

void print_ht(table *array[MAX_WORDS])
{
    // printf("address of the hash table inside print function: %p\n\n", array);

    table *cursor = malloc(sizeof(table));
    // add memory check

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_WORDS; i++)
    {
        printf("[%i] -> ", i);
        cursor = array[i];
        if (cursor->next)
        {
            table *temp = malloc(sizeof(table));
            temp = cursor->next;

            printf("%s\n", temp->text);
            free(temp);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("empty\n");
        }
    }
    free(cursor);
}
```

I'm sure there are other problems with this code, and I appreciate any other advice anyone would be willing to give here. For instance, I always wonder which parts of the code need to be their own functions and which should/can be combined together. It seems that some of this stuff should be separated out, but I've had a lot of trouble figuring out how to properly pass info from one function to another.

**UPDATE #1** (after some of the comments):

Yay, this works now!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUF_SIZE_WORDS 4096
#define BUF_SIZE_NUMBERS 256
#define MAX_WORDS 10

typedef struct tablestruct
{
    int val;
    char* text;
    struct tablestruct *next;
}
table;


// declare the hashing function that takes in the string to be hashed and the length of it
unsigned int hash(char *str, int length);

// // declare a linked list creation function
// lnode *createnode(char *str, htnode *hashtable);

// declare a hash table printing function
void print_ht(table *array[MAX_WORDS]);


int number_input();
int word_input(int num_words, table *array[MAX_WORDS]);
void empty_stdin();

int main(void)
{
    // call number_input() to ask user for number of words they'd like to store, save that in word_count
    int word_count = number_input();

    // create hash table
    table *array[MAX_WORDS];

    for (int j = 0; j < MAX_WORDS; j++)
    {
        array[j] = malloc(sizeof(table));
        array[j]->val = j;
    }

    // add some kind of a memory check?

    // PUT word_input inside the if statement to make sure it worked?
    // call word_input() and store the result in success
    int success = word_input(word_count, array);
    // if not successful:
    if (!success)
    {
        fputs ("some kind of problem with word_input\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    // printf("\ncurrent address of the hash table: %p\n", &array[0]);

    printf("printing hash table: \n");

    print_ht(array);

    // REMEMBER TO FREE WHATEVER'S MALLOC'ED
}

int number_input(void)
{
    // a bunch of code is borrowed from David's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52920852/why-is-the-following-code-not-allowing-me-to-get-user-input-with-fgets-yet-works?noredirect=1#comment92940817_52920852

    int num_words = 0,       /* number of words to enter */
        word_count_check = 0;          /* word count */

    char buffer[BUF_SIZE_NUMBERS] = "";    /* buffer of sufficient size for input */

    for (;;) /* loop continually until valid input of NUMBER OF WORDS USER WANTS TO ENTER or user cancels */
    {
        printf ("how many words would you like to enter? [1-%d]: ", MAX_WORDS);
        // check for cancellation of input
        if (!fgets (buffer, BUF_SIZE_NUMBERS, stdin))
        {
            fputs ("user canceled input\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }

        // check if user simply hit enter w/o typing anything
        if(buffer[0] == '\n')
        {
            printf("please enter a value\n");
            continue;
        }

        size_t inlength = strlen(buffer);

        if (inlength && buffer[inlength - 1] == '\n')
        {
            // printf("hurray!\n");
            buffer[--inlength] = 0;
        }
        else if (inlength == BUF_SIZE_NUMBERS - 1) /* the line was too long */
        {
            printf("you've entered too many characters... please stick to a maximum of %i\n", BUF_SIZE_NUMBERS);
            empty_stdin();
            // continue;
        }

        // make sure user actually entered a proper int
        if (sscanf (buffer, "%d", &num_words) != 1) /* sscanf is used for conversion */
        {
            fputs ("invalid conversion to int; please provide valid input\n", stderr);
            continue;
        }

        // check if the number entered is out of range
        if (num_words < 1 || num_words > MAX_WORDS)
            fprintf (stderr, "%2d out of valid range.\n", num_words);
        else
            break; /*if the input has been validated, we can now break out of the for loop */
    }

    return(num_words);
}

int word_input(int num_words, table *array[MAX_WORDS])
{
    int word_count = 0;

    for(;;) /* loop until word_count == num_words is achieved */
    {
        // declare an array for storing input string
        char buffer[BUF_SIZE_WORDS];
        char valid_input[BUF_SIZE_WORDS];

        // prompt user for input
        printf("\nplease enter a string: ");

        // get input and check for CTRL+D
        if (!fgets(buffer, BUF_SIZE_WORDS, stdin))
        {
            fputs ("user canceled input\n", stderr);
            exit(1);
        }

         // check if user simply hit enter w/o typing anything
        if(buffer[0] == '\n')
        {
            printf("please enter a word that's more than 0 characters\n");
            // empty_stdin();
            continue;
        }

        size_t inlength = strlen(buffer);

        if (inlength && buffer[inlength - 1] == '\n')
        {
            buffer[--inlength] = 0;

            // get rid of trailing spaces using sscanf
            sscanf(buffer, "%s", valid_input);
            inlength = strlen(valid_input);

            printf("string length: %zu\n", inlength);

            // call the hash function to get the hash code
            int result = hash(&valid_input[0], inlength);

            table *newnode = malloc(sizeof(table));
            newnode->text = malloc(strlen(valid_input)+1);
            strcpy(newnode->text, valid_input);

            // confirm string has been stored
            printf("you've entered: %s\n", newnode->text);

            // attach the node to correct slot in the hash table -- ADD LINKED LIST FUNCTIONALITY HERE TO DEAL WITH COLLISIONS!
            array[result]->next = newnode;
            // printf("address of the current HT entry is: %p\n", newnode);

            // increment word count
            word_count++;
            printf("word_count = %i\n", word_count);

            if (word_count == num_words)
            {
                 printf("\nDONE!\n\n");
                 return word_count;
            }
        }
        // check if the user entered too many characters
        else if (inlength == BUF_SIZE_WORDS - 1) /* the line was too long */
        {
            printf("you've entered too many characters... please stick to a maximum of %i\n", BUF_SIZE_WORDS);
            empty_stdin();
        }
    }
    // return word_count;
}


/* helper function to remove any chars left in input buffer */
void empty_stdin()
{
    int c = getchar();
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}

// THIS HASH FUNCTION IS TOO BASIC AND NEEDS TO BE REPLACED WITH SOMETHING BETTER
unsigned int hash(char *str, int length)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
    {
        sum += str[j];
    }
    printf("here's what the hashing function is returning: %i\n", (sum % MAX_WORDS));
    return sum % MAX_WORDS;
}

void print_ht(table *array[MAX_WORDS])
{
    // printf("address of the hash table inside print function: %p\n\n", array);

    table *cursor; // = malloc(sizeof(table));
    // add memory check

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_WORDS; i++)
    {
        printf("[%i] -> ", i);
        cursor = array[i];
        if (cursor->next)
        {
            table *temp; //= malloc(sizeof(table));
            temp = cursor->next;

            printf("%s\n", temp->text);
            // free(temp);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("empty\n");
        }
    }
    // free(cursor);
}
```

Comment: There are so many issues with this code :-/ but the main problem is in print_ht, why are you malloc'ing ANYTHING in a function that's only supposed to be printing stuff that's already there?

Comment: It's because the hash table entries you create contain pointers that are pointing to automatic storage class variables. `newnode->text = valid_input;` but `valid_input` is defined as local variable `char valid_input[BUF_SIZE_WORDS];`. `newnode->text` should point to memory allocated from the heap.

Comment: This is essentially the same problem as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50591226/10396

Comment: If you have the `strdup` function available, you can do `newnode->text = strdup(valid_input);`. Otherwise, `newnode->text = malloc(strlen(valid_input)+1); strcpy(newnode->text, valid_input);`.

Comment: It's this time of the year again, and over here we can observe a majestic specimen of `something = malloc(...); something = somethingelse;` in its natural habitat. The species, scientifically called *Monstratorem quaeque*, is classified as "least concern" because of its robust reproductive cycle and abundance of prey.

Comment: thanks! for some reason, I thought that every time the outer for(;;) loop would execute, a new buffer for valid_input would be created... @AhmedMasud thanks for pointing that out! not sure why I didn't realize that :)

Comment: @AhmedMasud if you have the time, I'd love to hear about the other issues with my code (I've updated it since your last comment, see Update 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `newnode->text = valid_input;` for each node.  But `valid_input` is a local buffer declared inside the scope of the for loop in `word_input`.   So this is not valid code - the buffer is not guaranteed to exist outside that function.

Practically, `valid_input` contains the address of some stack memory, which gets re-used every time you enter this function, so all the `node->text` pointers end up pointing to the same memory containing the last value entered.

You should be able to verify this is the case by printing the value of the text pointer for all the nodes.

What you need to do is create a new buffer for each entry you want to save.