# free(): invalid pointer when freeing a 2d pointer

Tags: c, pointers, free

I have a 2d pointer array:

```
char **fields = calloc(1, sizeof(char *));
```

I add to it different strings, like this:

```
if(i > 0) fields = realloc(fields, (i+1) * sizeof(char *));
fields[i] = calloc(size, sizeof(char));
```

I then use `memcpy` into the `fields[i]` the desired string.

At the end of the program, when I try to free fields, I do it like this:

```
int j=0
while(fields != NULL && fields[j]){
    free(fields[j]);
    j++;
}
free(fields);
```

The program inserts 4 strings into fields.
The first string frees as expected, however on the second iteration of the loop (j=1) the program stops and outputs the error: `free(): invalid pointer`

EDIT: I made a short program with the same problem:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char **fields = calloc(1, sizeof(char *));
    int fieldsIndex = 0,i=0;
    while (i<4) {
        if(fieldsIndex > 0){
            fields = realloc(fields, (fieldsIndex + 1) * sizeof(char *));
            fields[fieldsIndex] =NULL;
            printf("amount of field places: %d\n", (fieldsIndex + 1));
        }

        fields[fieldsIndex] = calloc(8, sizeof(char));
        fields[fieldsIndex] = "88888888";
        fieldsIndex++;
        i++;
    }
    int j=0;
    for(j=0; j<i; j++){
        printf("field: %s\n", fields[j]);
        free(fields[j]);
    }
    free(fields);
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean by an extra sentinel pointer? Can you give me an example in code? thanks

Comment: How about *you* give *us* a [mre]?  The code fragments presented are not inherently wrong, but they may rely on unsafe assumptions.  Or there my be an entirely separate issue.

Comment: It still doesn't work after changing it to a for loop like you mentioned. I made sure that all of pointers are allocated. I printed each field inside the loop and it printed the strings, meaning that the fields are still allocated, because the code I showed you is the only place I modify the fields variable in any way

Comment: By the time you free it, it is clearly wrong before that, but you have nit shown that code.  You have shown the `calloc()` call, but tot the code that determined the value of `i` at that point, nor anot other code that might corrupt `fields[1]`.  Essentially, none of the code you have posted includes the the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: While `calloc()` will set the sentinal to NULL, `realloc()` will not do so - you need to set `fields[i] = NULL` after `realloc()`. That is not the problem you mentioned, but it will be your next problem if you solve  this one.  In your debugger, note the value of `fields[1]` at allocation, then on release check it is the same.  It will be far easier for you with sight of all the code and the tools to debug it that to expect use to figure it out looking through the keyhole view you have provided.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, but how can fields[1] be corrupted if I can print it's value?
EDIT: the value is the same on allocation and release

Comment: @ItaiElidan :  Let me count the ways!  I am not about to guess though, you need to present the whole code - heap corruption can occur anywhere.  If the code is large you will have to reproduce the error in some smaller reproducible example.  If you cannot do that then clearly the code you are reducing it to is not where the error is.

Comment: I made a short program that outputs the problem

Comment: A "sentinel pointer" is an extra null pointer at the *end* of the array. You use it to know when you reach the end of the array, just like the nul character at the end of a "string".

Comment: Thank you, your suggestions solved my problem.

Comment: [Sigh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53089336/why-is-my-print-function-overwriting-previous-entries-with-the-last-entry-in-the-following-code#comment93077524_53089336). I think I should write a FAQ...

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. there's an idea, though I find it hard to believe that one doesn't exist  already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Addressing mainly the MRE.

- The main problems are around this line:

  ```
  fields[fieldsIndex] = "88888888";
  ```

  It's not right for two reasons:

  - Firstly you need one more element in the array for the null byte.
  - Secondly, you make the `fields[fieldsIndex]` pointers point to string literals, it not only causes a memory leak, but also those string literals are usually stored in a readonly section of memory, either way the behavior freeing a pointer pointing to a string literal is undefined.

    You need to copy the strings to the memory you just allocated. Using `memcpy` should work as long as you reserve enough memory as mentioned in the previous point, a cleaner way would be to use [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup).
- Another issue is `if(fieldsIndex > 0)` because then `fields[0]` will not have allocated memory.

Some other notes, if you know the amount of strings (`i < 4`) you shouldn't need to `realloc`, just allocate space for all the pointers in the first `calloc`<sup>*</sup> (assuming that is not brought about by the construction of the MRE) , also `i` and `fieldsIndex` seem to be redundant.

[Here is a demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xG1bofK3G) keeping `realloc` (as it's tangential to the OP):

```
int main()
{
    char **fields = NULL;
    char **tempfields; // I advise the use of an auxiliary pointer for reallocation
    int fieldsIndex = 0;

    while (fieldsIndex < 4)
    {
        tempfields = realloc(fields, (fieldsIndex + 1) * sizeof *fields); //*
        if (!tempfields)
        {         
            // handle the allocation error appropriately
        }
        fields = tempfields;
        printf("amount of field places: %d\n", (fieldsIndex + 1));
        fields[fieldsIndex] = strdup("88888888");
        // Or 
        // fields[fieldsIndex] = calloc(9, sizeof **fields); // check return
        // strcpy(fields[fieldsIndex], "88888888");

        fieldsIndex++;
    }

    // With int iterator
    int j = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < fieldsIndex; j++)
    {
        printf("field: %s\n", fields[j]);
        free(fields[j]);
    }
    free(fields);
}
```

Or with a sentinel element in `fields`:

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/33aqafrcr)

```
// With sentinel
tempfields = realloc(fields, (fieldsIndex + 1) * sizeof *fields);
if (!tempfields)
{
     // handle the allocation error appropriately
}
fields = tempfields;
fields[fieldsIndex] = NULL;

while (*fields)
{
    printf("field: %s\n", *fields);
    free(*fields);
    fields++;
}
free(tempfields);
```